# iOS Crash: Terminating app due to uncaught exception reason: UIPopoverPresentationController should have a non-nil sourceView

Tags: ios, objective-c, crash, uipopovercontroller

I need help figuring this crash out. I checked stackoverflow for answers, but non of the answers relates to my situation. This is my code.

```
  - (void)addImagesActionSheetClickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // Cancel
    if (buttonIndex == 2) return;

    //Take picture
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        //Take picture
        isFromLibrary = NO;
        [self.imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
        return;
    }

    // Library picture
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {

    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum]) return;

    UIPopoverController *popup = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.imagePicker];
    [popup presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/4, 0, 0)inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
}
```

If I click button index 1 and dismiss the `UIPopoverController` then click button index 0 to take a picture my App crashes.

Here is my crash report

> 'Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSGenericException',
>   reason: 'UIPopoverPresentationController
>   () should have a non-nil
>   sourceView or barButtonItem set before the presentation occurs.

Any suggestions or tips are appreciated. If I need to post more code, please let me know.

Comment: see here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42920340/uipopoverpresentationcontroller-should-have-a-non-nil-sourceview-or-barbuttonite/71193425#71193425

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a strong reference to `popup`

`@property (nonatomic, strong) UIPopoverController *popup;`

Then use

```
 - (void)addImagesActionSheetClickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    // Cancel
    if (buttonIndex == 2) return;

    //Take picture
    if (buttonIndex == 0)
    {
        //Take picture
        isFromLibrary = NO;
        [self.imagePicker setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
        [self.navigationController presentViewController:self.imagePicker animated:YES completion:NULL];
        return;
    }

    // Library picture
    if (buttonIndex == 1)
    {

    if (![UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable: UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeSavedPhotosAlbum]) return;

        self.popup = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:self.imagePicker];
        [self.popup presentPopoverFromRect:CGRectMake(self.view.frame.size.width/2, self.view.frame.size.height/4, 0, 0)inView:self.view permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
    }
}
```

And implement `UIPopoverControllerDelegate`

in

```
- (void)popoverControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController{

    self.popup = nil;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice the discussion in the documentation :

`sourceRect`

> Use this property in conjunction with the sourceView property to specify the anchor location for the popover. Alternatively, you may specify the anchor location for the popover using the barButtonItem property.

Pretty clear and concise. Just add a sourceView reference

https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIPopoverPresentationController_class/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UIPopoverPresentationController/sourceRect